# Express-like framework for building APIs

Tags: express, go

I have built some basic APIs with the node.js Express framework. I'm thinking of switching to Go, since callback code gets hard to reason about pretty quickly. I really like Express as a framework, is there something similar in Go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gorilla Toolkit is great.  In particular, you might want to look at github.com/gorilla/mux.  Larger frameworks exist, but go users tend to opt for the simpler option, because the language and standard library get you quite far and a framework isn't as necessary to manage the complexity as it is in other languages and may just complicate things unnecessarily.

The [API docs](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/gorilla/mux) are a good reference and you can also check out [examples of how other people use it](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/gorilla/mux/symbols/go/github.com/gorilla/mux).

Answer (score 5):

This maybe too late for you but I've been working on a clone of Express for Go. I claim it to be 90% complete so as long as it's the right 90% it could work for you.

Source: https://github.com/ricallinson/forgery Site: http://goforgery.appspot.com/

Comment: that seems like a dead project

Answer (score 2):

I've found go-api helpful, but there are several other frameworks out there. If you're looking for a more basic package, the Gorilla Toolkit (note: It's a toolkit, not a framework, so it's much less opinionated)

GoApi: https://github.com/dpapathanasiou/go-api
Gorilla: https://github.com/gorilla

Comment: The most closed to the expressjs is the [iris web framework](https://github.com/kataras/iris) which is mantained by me. Note that I was nodejs developer for many years. Late answer but hope someone will be helpful from this.

Comment: @kataras turn this comment into an answer, it deserves to be one

Answer (score 2):

Maybe not that similar, but give a look at [Revel](http://robfig.github.io/revel/)

Comment: Th author asked for similar ;) not for, non similar to try out ;)